# How to operate with factors in data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, factors

i'm new in R, and i try to operate with data frame:
[screen](http://prntscr.com/k76jf6)
how to get numeric array from row 10 
ar <-df[10,1] did't work

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! This site could help improving your post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example.

Comment: Another good resource for improving your question: [ask]

Comment: Is that JSON? You might do something like `lapply(df$ym.s.goalsID, jsonlite::fromJSON)` to have everything broken out. If you need it to remain in the frame, you might switch to a "tidy" way of dealing with frames such as in the `tidyverse` using packages `tidyr` and `purrr`. Good reference for them: http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/

Comment: no, its factor, here is output: http://prntscr.com/k774ua

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gsub` to remove brackets. Please see the code below:

```
# Simulation
x <- factor(c("[1]", "[2,3]", "[4]", "[]"))
str(x)
# Factor w/ 4 levels "[]","[1]","[2,3]",..: 2 3 4 1


foobar <- lapply(x, function(x) {
  # remove brackets
 s <- gsub("\\[||\\]", "", as.character(x)) 
 as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(s, split = ",")))
})

str(foobar)
```

Output:

```
List of 4
 $ : num 1
 $ : num [1:2] 2 3
 $ : num 4
 $ : num(0)
```